# How to add iOS Simulators in XCode 14?

Tags: xcode, xcode14

iOS simulators isn't listed under Platform tab in Preference. Please see images below.

I tried to google but I could not found my same problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode and macOS do you have? How did you install Xcode? There should be at least one iOS version showing as Built-in on the Platforms tab.

Comment: Im on Monterey 12.6.3. I installed XCode from the App Store, so I have the latest version which is 14.3.